# Does anyone know of a library that will manipulate data based on time intervals?

Tags: java, time, recommendation-engine

Does anyone know of a library that can manipulate/organize data based on time intervals?

For example:

- I have a collection of data that is mapped by Date/Time to Object [Could be anything, a list of unrelated data, Strings, numbers, etc]
- I would like for a Collection to be generic enough so that it could handle the interval searches, organizations, merges, intersections, differences, and interval changes [i.e. the collection would reorganize an 15minute interval going to a 1 day interval]

I was thinking about writing one of these, but I'd rather not reinvent the wheel.

Also, the last stipulation, is that I'd like it to be in Java.

For example:

> You have the following data:
>
> - 1/1/11 1:01 - "Bob entered the room"
> - 1/1/11 12:01 - "Jerry entered the room"
> - 1/1/11 1:31 - "Sally entered the room"
> - 1/1/11 1:51 - "Jorge entered the room"
> - 1/1/11 2:01 - "Dilbert entered the room"
> - 1/2/11 1:01 - "Bob entered the room"
> - 1/3/11 12:01 - "Jerry entered the room"
> - 1/2/11 1:31 - "Sally entered the room"
> - 1/2/11 1:51 - "Jorge entered the room"
>
> All of the enteries stated here [as a 2 value datum] would go into the collection [i.e.]: add(Date, object)
>      However on initialization the interval would be set. [I.e. 15minutes]
>      So if the interval was 15 minutes [and queried for a specific time. It would produce:
>
> - 1/1/11 12:00-12:15
>
>   - "Jerry entered the room"
> - 1/1/11 1:00-1:15
>         - "Bob entered the room"
> - 1/1/11 1:15-1:30
> - 1/1/11 1:30-1:45
>
>   - 1/1/11 1:31 - "Sally entered the room"
>       ....
>
>   If you tried to query for 1/1/11 12:09, you'd get the results for 1/1/11 12:00-12:15.
>     Yes I realize there are edge cases, but this is an example.

Comment: It's hard to understand what you are asking. How about writing a couple of test cases to show how the thing should work?

Comment: Wouldn't there be issues when it comes to modifying the interval? I was looking at extending a hashmap, making the hash based on the interval, but that would fail when the interval is changed. q

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the sketch of a `TreeMap` wrapper that does basically what your example shows:

```
public class CalendarMap<V> {

    private TreeMap<Calendar, V> map = new TreeMap<Calendar, V>();

    public void put(Calendar d, V v){
        map.put(d, v);
    }

    public void query(Calendar d, int intervalUnit, int intervalValue){
         DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy");
         DateFormat tf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");

        // snap closest prior unit
        d.set(intervalUnit, (d.get(intervalUnit) / intervalValue)* intervalValue);
        Calendar next = new GregorianCalendar();
        next.setTime(d.getTime());
        next.add(intervalUnit, intervalValue);

        Calendar lastHit = null; // last hit

        while(d.before(map.lastKey())){
            SortedMap<Calendar, V> hits = map.subMap(d, true, next, false);
            if(!hits.isEmpty()){
                if(lastHit != null){
                    System.out.println(df.format(lastHit.getTime()) + " " + tf.format(lastHit.getTime()) + " - " + 
                            df.format(d.getTime()) + " " + tf.format(d.getTime()) + ": N/A");
                    lastHit = null;
                }
                System.out.println(df.format(d.getTime()) + " " + tf.format(d.getTime()) + "-" + tf.format(next.getTime()) + ":");
                for(Entry<Calendar, V> entry : hits.entrySet()){
                    System.out.println("  " + tf.format(entry.getKey().getTime()) + " - " + entry.getValue());
                }
            }else if(lastHit == null){
                lastHit = new GregorianCalendar();
                lastHit.setTime(d.getTime());
            }
            d.add(intervalUnit, intervalValue);
            next.add(intervalUnit, intervalValue);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        CalendarMap<String> map = new CalendarMap<String>();
        map.put(new GregorianCalendar(2011, 1, 1, 13, 1), "Bob entered the room");
        map.put(new GregorianCalendar(2011, 1, 1, 12, 1), "Jerry entered the room");
        map.put(new GregorianCalendar(2011, 1, 1, 13, 31), "Sally entered the room");
        map.put(new GregorianCalendar(2011, 1, 1, 14, 1), "Dilbert entered the room");
        map.put(new GregorianCalendar(2011, 1, 2, 13, 1), "Bob entered the room");
        map.put(new GregorianCalendar(2011, 1, 3, 12, 1), "Jerry entered the room");
        map.put(new GregorianCalendar(2011, 1, 2, 13, 31), "Sally entered the room");
        map.put(new GregorianCalendar(2011, 1, 2, 13, 51), "Jorge entered the room");

        map.query(new GregorianCalendar(2011, 1, 1, 12, 9), Calendar.MINUTE, 15);
    }

}
```

This produces:

```
Feb 01, 2011 12:00-12:15:
  12:01 - Jerry entered the room
Feb 01, 2011 12:15 - Feb 01, 2011 13:00: N/A
Feb 01, 2011 13:00-13:15:
  13:01 - Bob entered the room
Feb 01, 2011 13:15 - Feb 01, 2011 13:30: N/A
Feb 01, 2011 13:30-13:45:
  13:31 - Sally entered the room
Feb 01, 2011 13:45 - Feb 01, 2011 14:00: N/A
Feb 01, 2011 14:00-14:15:
  14:01 - Dilbert entered the room
Feb 01, 2011 14:15 - Feb 02, 2011 13:00: N/A
Feb 02, 2011 13:00-13:15:
  13:01 - Bob entered the room
Feb 02, 2011 13:15 - Feb 02, 2011 13:30: N/A
Feb 02, 2011 13:30-13:45:
  13:31 - Sally entered the room
Feb 02, 2011 13:45-14:00:
  13:51 - Jorge entered the room
Feb 02, 2011 14:00 - Feb 03, 2011 12:00: N/A
Feb 03, 2011 12:00-12:15:
  12:01 - Jerry entered the room
```

Suppose instead you execute this:

```
map.query(new GregorianCalendar(2011, 1, 1, 12, 9), Calendar.HOUR, 1);
```

Then the output is:

```
Feb 01, 2011 12:09-13:09:
  13:01 - Bob entered the room
Feb 01, 2011 13:09-14:09:
  13:31 - Sally entered the room
  14:01 - Dilbert entered the room
Feb 01, 2011 14:09 - Feb 02, 2011 12:09: N/A
Feb 02, 2011 12:09-13:09:
  13:01 - Bob entered the room
Feb 02, 2011 13:09-14:09:
  13:31 - Sally entered the room
  13:51 - Jorge entered the room
Feb 02, 2011 14:09 - Feb 03, 2011 11:09: N/A
Feb 03, 2011 11:09-12:09:
  12:01 - Jerry entered the room
```

Comment: So the interval value unit is an numerical value that represents a day, month, hour, second, etc? The interval value is say 15 [for 15s]? This looks close to what I was looking for. Also, I would upvote more since you used Calendar :P But I can only do that once. My approach was a bit more lengthy if I were to do it manually. Thanks! I learned something. :)

Comment: @monsky: `Calendar.MINUTE` defines an `int` that means "minute" and is the contents of `intervalUnit` and the parameter to a number of functions. `intervalValue` is the number of units, so for `Calendar.MINUTE` with value `15`, this means "15 minutes. I fixed some bugs in my code and gave you an output that actually matches yours above.

Comment: @monsky: also, the query function now takes the interval, so you can query for different intervals as you like (see updated example output)

Comment: @monsky: last edit from me on this...updated to improve dead-interval handling, when there's several intervals with nothing I collapse them.

Comment: Thank you!!! If we ever meet in a bar I'll buy you a beer. Thats kinda awesome! I wasn't expecting that much.